# How does ExceptionMapper workes in EVERREST with JAX-RS?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, codenvy, javax

I want to understand the logic of JAX-RS with  ExceptionMapper

lets assume that I have class

```
    @Provider
    @Singleton
    public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ApiException> {

        /**
         * check the exception type and build Response with the status body and the type of the error
         */
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(ApiException exception) {
            ........
        }
    }
```

How is call this class ?
I saw that there is class ApplicationPrivderBinder that has method getExceptionMapper

Does it is the logic?

Who call to this method ? where is the call to the method toResponse from the

```
interface ExceptionMapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAX-RS framework does automatically call this when an exception of the specified type (here: ApiException) propagates out of a resource method.

Comment: By "everrest" you're refering to SerfJ (http://serfj.sourceforge.net/), right? It does implement the JAX-RS standard, so it will behave the same way, since exception mappers are defined by JAX-RS.